# Golang godror - execute a PL/SQL Cursor

Tags: oracle, go, plsql

I'm trying to retrieve cursor result of a PL/SQL function in golang with godror.

https://github.com/godror/godror

> Using cursors returned by stored procedures
>   Use ExecContext and an interface{} or a database/sql/driver.Rows as the sql.Out destination, then either use the driver.Rows interface, or transform it into a regular *sql.Rows with godror.WrapRows, or (since Go 1.12) just Scan into *sql.Rows.

```
db, err := sql.Open("godror", "api/user@localhost/DEV")
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
  panic(err)
}
defer db.Close()

ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
defer cancel()

const query = `
DECLARE
BEGIN
:cursor := pkg_api.my_func(pstr_logn_nm => 'my_name');
END;
`
stmt, err := db.PrepareContext(ctx, query)
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
  panic(err)
}

var rows driver.Rows
_, err = stmt.ExecContext(ctx, sql.Out{Dest: &rows})
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
}

var r []driver.Value
err = rows.Next(r)
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err) // column count mismatch: we have 10 columns, but given 0 destination
}
defer rows.Close()

fmt.Println(rows.Columns()) // [COL_1 COL_2 COL_3 COL_4 COL_5 COL_6 COL_7 COL_8 COL_9 COL_10]
```

I have an error: `column count mismatch: we have 10 columns, but given 0 destination`
To my point of view it's because I have to define an interface with some columns.

If I try to change `driver.Rows` by `sql.Rows` I have this error:

> arg: unknown type sql.Rows

If I try to create an interface I:

```
type I interface {
  NM() string
}

var r []I
err = rows.Next(r)
```

I have this error: `cannot use r (type []I) as type []driver.Value in argument to rows.Next`

I'm also new in Golang, if someone has an idea :)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem!

```
r := make([]driver.Value, len(rows.Columns()))
err = rows.Next(r)
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err) // column count mismatch: we have 10 columns, but given 0 destination
}
defer rows.Close()
```

https://github.com/godror/godror/issues/62